# Query that combines 3 tables

Tags: postgresql

I need to display the names of projects on which employees from the department called "Programmers" work. I am stuck on this query, can someone help me?-

I got three tables.

departments where department id of 3 is Programmers

```
department_id
name
```

projects:

```
p_id
p_name
```

employees

```
id,
name,
department_id
```

```sql
SELECT p_name from PROJECTS
   WHERE...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the three tables you provided I do not think you can do it.  There is nothing linking projects to either employees or departments.  You will need another table (employeesOnProject or deparmentprojects, etc) to do it.